# Создание двух соединений к разным БД Oracle в Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Всем доброго времени суток, подскажите как сделать два и более подключений к разным БД средствами Hibernate ? большое спасибо

Comment: Используете чистый hibernate, со Spring или Tomcat/GlassFish/JBoss? В зависимости от этого могут быть разные рецепты.

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov Я только учусь и использовать Spring только начинаю, вы не могли бы поделиться примером ? Сервер поднят на Tomcat

Comment: Хороший пример на аннотациях вы найдете тут http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases